# How to implement the thread_local feature of C++11(TLS) in iOS8

Tags: ios, multithreading, c++11

In iOS App development, if we write the following code in Xcode and set the deployment target to 8.0(or below 9.0), an error message will appear:

```
static thread_local T inst;
```

The error message is:

> Thread-local storage is not supported for the current target

However, my app needs to support users that using iOS 8.0.

Is there a way to break through such restrictions? Or can you provide an alternative to thread_local under iOS8?

Comment: Do you *really* need to support iOS 8? All devices that run iOS 8 can also run iOS 9. iOS 8 is 5 years old. Apple announced today that 85% of users are on iOS 12.

Comment: @rmaddy yes of course. My app has about 10,000 users who are using iOS8 and have no willing to upgrade. I don't want to lose them.

Comment: An alternative to `thread_local` is to have each thread explicitly allocate and manage its data, e.g. on the heap.